# for loop syntax with if statements inside

Tags: loops, syntax, if-statement, for-loop, coding-style

What is the general consensus on writing for loops with if statements like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < hi; i++) {
    if (some invalid condition) {
        continue;
    }

    if (another invalid condition) {
        continue;
    }

    //do stuff here after passing all the invalid conditions
}
```

as opposed to

```
for (int i = 0; i < hi; i++) {
    if (valid condition1 && valid condition 2 && ...) {
        //do stuff
}
```

It seems to me that the first way of writing it is much cleaner and more convenient for debugging, though it takes up more lines. My main question is if there's ever any advantage to writing it the second way. Even when there is just one if statement, it seems like writing it the first way would be better to make it easier to maintain/debug in the future.

Answer (score 2):

'CONTINUE' in loops is pretty rare. In most cases encountering invalid situation inside a loop will naturally result in 'BREAK' instead. However there is nothing wrong with your example and it may indeed be more suitable if this fits your business logic.

Answer (score 0):

Some people don't like `continue` because it is effectively a `goto`. For example, consider:

```
for (int i = 0; i < hi; i++) {
    ....
    do_this_for_each_full_iteration();
}
```

If the `....` contains any `continue` statements, the `do_this_after_each_full_iteration()` will be bypassed.

These tend to be the same people who dislike `return`ing from the middle of a function.

Comment: What about break, why is it preferable?

Comment: `break` is less contentious because it exits the loop rather than pretending that the current iteration ran successfully. There are still people who dislike `break` though. Whereas `continue` and `return` mean that if you want to execute something "just before finishing" you have to add it at the end of the loop body/function *and* at every premature `continue`/`return`.

Comment: Good point, though I think this whole thing is overblown. I bet 90% of the people who don't use `goto` have no idea why.